# How to force all CPU cores to run at maximum turbo boost frequency?

Tags: centos, acpi, cpu-frequency, turbo-core

My goal is to force all CPU cores to run at maximum turbo frequency (4 x 3.9 GHz) using CentOS 7. Here is the output of `cpupower frequency-info`:

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us
  hardware limits: 1.60 GHz - 3.50 GHz
  available frequency steps:  3.50 GHz, 3.50 GHz, 3.30 GHz, 3.10 GHz, 2.90 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.30 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.60 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative userspace powersave ondemand performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.60 GHz and 3.50 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 3.50 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    3600 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    3700 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    3800 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    3900 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```

Turbo boost is working as expected - all 4 cores fully loaded are reaching 3.6 GHz. But it would be nice to have `3900 MHz max turbo 4 active cores` or less (at least 4 x 3.7 GHz). How to control it? 
Is it possible?

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329415/how-to-turbo-boost-my-cpu-on-ubuntu

Comment: IN fact you're CPU depending of the need and its temperature will or will not turbo boost. You could disable turboboost from your bios but you won't be able to force it. If you just want to test your CPU and push it to the limit use `stress --cpu 4 -t 60s` it will burn your CPU for 60 secondes

Comment: use `turbostat`  to watch real frequency in real time

Answer (score 4):

In short, no, it's not possible. As you can see from the output of `cpupower`, your CPU only supports a maximum of 3,600Mhz with 4 cores active. When it's running at 3,900Mhz only 1 core is active.

Those are the limits that were put in place by the CPU manufacturer. If you want more performance, overclocking is an option but that may introduce stability problems and you need to ensure you have sufficient cooling.

Comment: Yes, water cooling, stronger power supply, etc. is possible. But how to overclock - at least run 4 x 3.7 GHz?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis it's not the point of this site to help you tunning your computer. If you have question about Hardware you could post it on http://meta.superuser.com/

Comment: I don't think so - its software related also. Or perhaps CPU driver should be modified.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis If you overclock, the scaling frequencies will increase in line with the overclock (you'll need to benchmark to determine by exactly how much). If you only want to reach 4x3.7Ghz (an increase of only ~6% per core over the base 4x3.5Ghz), I'm not sure it's worth it...

Comment: Perhaps a little bit more - but it would be nice to have an option to control it.

Comment: -1 This answer is not accurate at all. You can override this setting by messing with CPU model specific registers.